# как вывести из mysql с 2 по 6 строку

Tags: mysql

как вывести со 2 по 6 строку из mysql

Answer (score 1):

Используются параметры `LIMIT <количество строк>` и `OFFSET <количество пропущенных строк>`:

`SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5 OFFSET 1`